# Is this a fragment or a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is this a sentence:
Seems we could use some shaping from our building practices today.

Answer (score 1):

Formally? No.

It's missing a subject.

But in informal settings it's fine. The subject is elided.

Our department seems we could use some shaping from our building practices today.

or

It seems we could use some shaping from our building practices today.

etc.

Comment: Thanks !    so with your 2nd suggestion, the subject would be 'It' , verb would be 'seems' , then what is the direct object?

Comment: The direct object is the NP _some shaping from our building practices_. The verb "seem" has no object, but has the content clause _we could use some shaping from our building practices today_ as complement. The main verb of that clause is transitive "use" which takes the aforementioned direct object.

Comment: The direct object of the subord clause (.. could use..) is not 'the' direct obj.  'Content clause is an obscuring name for a direct object which is an event.  'It' is 'nature it'; there is an elided 'that' after 'seems'; the direct obj of 'seems' is the entire clause 'we could use ...', which can be accomplished in memory by linking to its verb (could use).